# Run build process before copying files

Tags: continuous-integration, devops, github-actions, continuous-deployment

I have the following `deploy.yml`

```
name: Deploy

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1

    - name: Copy repository contents via scp
      uses: appleboy/scp-action@master
      env:
        HOST: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
        USERNAME: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
        PORT: ${{ secrets.PORT }}
        PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.PASSWORD }}
      with:
        source: "."
        target: "/var/www/html/cnaiapp"
        rm: true

    - name: Executing remote command
      uses: appleboy/ssh-action@develop
      with:
        host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
        USERNAME: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
        PORT: ${{ secrets.PORT }}
        PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.PASSWORD }}
        script: cd /var/www/html/cnaiapp && npm run deploy
```

However, the `master` branch has unminified and testing code, that I don't want to have in my VPS. Do you know how could I achieve this? BTW, in order to remove this unnecessary code, I'd need to run the `npm run build` command.

PS: The `npm run deploy` command just builds the code and starts the server.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a new [step with the run command](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsrun) after checkout:

```
…
jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: build
      run: npm run build
    - name: Copy repository contents via scp
    …
```